# How can I order item and subitem?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by

I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE lc (
    id CHARACTER(4),
    name TEXT
);
```

The column "id" has code value where there is item and subitem, for example:

Items

```
1, 2, 3 ... 10, 11 ...
```

Subitems :

```
101, 102, 201, 301 ... 1001, 1002, 1101 ...
```

Where, 101 is subitem of 1, 201 is subitem of 2, 1001 is subitem of 10, and so on.

How can I use "Order By" and have the following order:

```
1
101
102
2
201
...
10
1001
1002
11
1101
...
```

Comment: You should really change your table design and add a `parent` column to avoid such subitem structure

Comment: You are showing sample data until item 11. With more items, we'll reach item 101 sometime (which already is a subitem to item10). Its first subitem would be 10101. That would be placed between 101 and 102? I.e. 1, 101, 10101, 102, …?

Comment: @juergend, because is a code table of an organ of Brazil. https://www.ovalleleao.com.br/Publicacoes/40BitsLC116_03_NovaListaServicosComparada.pdf

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No! Only two levels... The first of 10 is 1001. I already solve! Thx!

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. The docs go up to item 40 and you think it guaranteed that item 101 will never be reached.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Exact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
select *
from lc
order by case when id::int < 100 then (id::int::text || '00')::int else id::int end
```

However, your table really needs a redesign.

Comment: I can not modify it because it is a code table of an organ of Brazil, which has this standard.

Comment: Why `id::int::text` and not `id`?

Comment: @forpas - because `character(4)` fills not used chars with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that some items are one digit (1, 2, etc.), some are two (10, 11, etc.).

You want odd numbers of digits first (1 or 3 digits: 1, 2, 101, 102, 201, ...), followed by even numbers of digits (2 or 4 digits: 10, 11, 1001, 1002, 1101, ...). Inside these two sets you want text order: '101' after '1' but before '2'.

```
select * 
from mytable
order by length(num::text) % 2 desc, num::text;
```